# How to convert Java String to Oracle Clob in stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle

I have a procedure as below

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  PROCESS_MESSAGE(
    MESSAGE_ENTITY IN T_MESSAGE_ENTITY,
    STATUS OUT VARCHAR2
.
.
```

where `T_MESSAGE_ENTITY` is the type which has some fields as `CLOB`

```
create or replace TYPE T_MESSAGE_ENTITY FORCE AS OBJECT (
COLS CLOB,
VALS CLOB
.
.
)
```

I have to pass `T_MESSAGE_ENTITY` to the procedure as the input parameter with these `CLOB` value I tried by using ARRAY.

```
objMsgEntityArray[0] = colString.getBytes();
objMsgEntityArray[1] = valString.getBytes();
```

and passing this object using `callableStmt.setObject()`

it's giving me below error.

> SQLException occurred while merging data into Issue
>   table.java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal
>   representation: [B@3cbbfe22  at
>   oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCLOB.toDatum(OracleTypeCLOB.java:71)

Answer (score 1):

If you are want to use udt (user defined type) in java you have to create mapping class using  java.sql.SQLData interface or
take advantage of STRUCT class.  In my example, i'm going to use the second option

Your type and procedure.

```
create or replace TYPE T_MESSAGE_ENTITY FORCE AS OBJECT (
  COLS CLOB,
  VALS CLOB    
);

create or replace PROCEDURE  PROCESS_MESSAGE(
    MESSAGE_ENTITY IN T_MESSAGE_ENTITY,
    STATUS OUT VARCHAR2) 
    is 
    begin         
     status := MESSAGE_ENTITY.cols||'-'|| MESSAGE_ENTITY.VALS;        
    end;
```

Java:

```
StructDescriptor structdesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("T_MESSAGE_ENTITY", con);
        Clob clob1 = con.createClob();
        clob1.setString(1,"First paramter");
        Clob clob2 = con.createClob();
        clob2.setString(1,"Secound paramter");
        Object[] attributes = {clob1,clob2};
        STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(structdesc, con, attributes);        
        String CALL_PROC = "{call PROCESS_MESSAGE(?,?)}";
        CallableStatement  callableStatement = con.prepareCall(CALL_PROC);
        callableStatement.setObject(1, struct, Types.STRUCT);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.err.println(callableStatement.getString(2));
```

Comment: Tried this but its giving me below error. SQLException occurred while merging data into Issue table.java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB@56

Comment: oracle.sql.CLOB clobCols = (CLOB) connection.createClob();
did like this but giving below error : Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB

Comment: Weblogic wrap each object in the own class. There is the way to turn off this mechanism. Or you can try one more time with this interface `oracle.jdbc.OracleClob`. Last option is update JDBC driver to newest possible version. And retest everything.

Comment: Tried with oracle.jdbc.OracleClob but its unresolved. Also i cant turn off weblogic mechanism on PROD. But thanks for you response.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to turn off / uncheck the Wrap Data Types  . An alternate workaround is to use the following code

```
    if(obj instanceof weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob) {
      weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob clob = (weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob)st1.getObject(2);
      **Clob oc = (oracle.sql.CLOB)clob.unwrap(Class.forName("oracle.sql.CLOB"));**
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by using the below code to create CLOB object -

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleClob clobCols = (oracle.jdbc.OracleClob) conn.createClob();
clobCols.setString(1, "String value")
```

The second thing which you need is to uncheck the "Wrap Data Types" property of the data source for which you have acquired the DB connection. Even on production, it is a better idea to uncheck this property as doing that will improve the performance of the application.

```
By default, data type objects for Array, Blob, Clob, NClob, Ref, SQLXML, and Struct, 
plus ParameterMetaData and ResultSetMetaData objects are wrapped with a WebLogic 
wrapper.Which converts or wrappes Oracle type to Weblogic type which is extra and 
expensive operation so it is recommended to uncheck this property for getting better 
performance.
```